# send attachment in newsletter magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to send attachment with newsletter in magento, I want to find, which file is using for sending newsletter email. I tried with this file `/app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php` and add attachment code `sendConfirmationRequestEmail` in this function, but its not a write file. Can any one help ?

Answer (score 4):

I found file in which I need to make change, its `/app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php` and I just added code in `sendPerSubscriber()` function inside foreach loop

```
        foreach($collection->getItems() as $item) {
        $email = $item->getSubscriberEmail();
        $name = $item->getSubscriberFullName();

        $sender->emulateDesign($item->getStoreId());


        //sending file as attachment code start

            $fileName="PSB_ONLINE.pdf";//file to be attach                                          
            $attachmentFilePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS . $fileName;
            if(file_exists($attachmentFilePath)){
                $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachmentFilePath);                    
                $attachment   = $sender->getMail()->createAttachment($fileContents);
                $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
                $attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
                $attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;                 
                $attachment->filename = $fileName;
                }
     //sending file as attachment end


        $successSend = $sender->send($email, $name, array('subscriber' => $item));
        $sender->revertDesign();

        if($successSend) {
            $item->received($this);
        } else {
            $problem = Mage::getModel('newsletter/problem');
            $notification = Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Please refer to exeption.log');
            $problem->addSubscriberData($item)
                ->addQueueData($this)
                ->addErrorData(new Exception($notification))
                ->save();
            $item->received($this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please accept your own question. Please do it friend.